# How to convert string to float in cpp

Tags: c++

I want to convert string to float. I used the function std::atof, but when i have a string of zero this does not work because the return number of std::atof is 0 if it was succesful.
Some of the strings are not numbers.
There for, with this code i wrote:

```
  float att_valur_converted;
        att_valur_converted = std::atof(m_pAttr->att_value);
        if (att_valur_converted != 0.0){      
        sprintf(m_pAttr->att_value,"%.2f", att_valur_converted);
```

This will not work for zero.
What can I do so this will work for zero?
Thanks.

Comment: [`strtof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtof), [`istringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream/basic_istringstream), [`sscanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf), ... You should find some duplicates here on SO.

Comment: "the return number of std::atof is 0 if it was succesful" -> "the return number of std::atof is 0 if it was **not** succesful"

Comment: Use [std::stof](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof), as pointed out in one of the answers in the question this one is marked a duplicate of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`std::stod`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) for such operations if you have access to C++11.

Otherwise use `std::stringstream` as in the following:

```
double f = 0.0;    
std::stringstream ss;
std::string s = "213.1415";    
ss << s;
ss >> f;  //f now contains the converted string into a double  
cout << f;
```

Of course in both cases you have to deal with the fact the such conversion might fail for instance if you try to call `stod` with "blablabla" as input.

The two methods that I suggested deal with this scenario in two different ways:

1. `stod` throws an exception that you can catch
2. `sstream` sets a flag that you can query using `bool ss.good()`. `good` will return true is the conversion was successful, false otherwise.

Comment: Thanks,I forgot to mention that some of the strings are not numbers. I see std::stod cannot deal with this.. do you know anything else?

Comment: if the string you are passing cannot be converted then stod deals with it by throwing an exception that you can catch.

Comment: It is also recommended to check the status of the extraction,  "if(ss.good()) { okToUsef(f) } else { DidNotConvertSo_handleError(); }